# How to create modal popup in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog, android-popupwindow

I'm not up to date with Android solutions and I wonder what is the most current way to display popup/modal/alert dialog in application?

2 years ago I used to use alert (or fragment) dialogs with custom view. I heard that nowadays this is possible by special activity.

What are the current patterns for that case?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `android:theme` to make an activity look like a dialog. Add a tag similar to this to your activity in the Android Manifest.

```
<activity 
....
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog"
..../>
```